# Using JavaFileManager to compile projects

Tags: java, compiler-construction, multiple-projects

I'm currently creating a system that will allow the user to compile a single or multiple projects. I have been doing a bit of research and have decided to use the JavaCompilerAPI to do this. I have being playing around with it and have managed to get single java files compiling and a list of single java files compiling.

What i am not able to do is get a single java project compiling let alone a group of them. I read somewhere that you can use the JavaFileManager to do this and I have read up on it a bit but i am unable to find any examples of this so I'm stuck.

This is what i have done so far:

```
public List doCompilation(String sourceCode, String locationOfFile) {
   List<String> compile = new ArrayList<>();

    SimpleJavaFileObject fileObject = new DynamicJavaSourceCodeObject(locationOfFile, sourceCode);
    JavaFileObject javaFileObjects[] = new JavaFileObject[]{fileObject};

    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    StandardJavaFileManager stdFileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, Locale.getDefault(), null);

    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(javaFileObjects);

    String[] compileOptions = new String[]{"-d", "C:/projects/Compiler/TempBINfolder/bin"};
    Iterable<String> compilationOptions = Arrays.asList(compileOptions);

    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

    CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, stdFileManager, diagnostics, compilationOptions, null, compilationUnits);

    boolean status = compilerTask.call();

    if (!status) {//If compilation error occurs 
        // Iterate through each compilation problem and print it
        for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) { 
            compile.add(diagnostic.getKind().toString()+" on line  "+ diagnostic.getLineNumber() +"\nIn file:  \n"+ diagnostic.toString()+"\n\n");
        }
    }
    try {
        stdFileManager.close();//Close the file manager
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return compile;
}
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "java project"?  How is it different from a set of java files (each of which you can compile individually)?  What are the problems you are experiencing when trying to compile a "project"?

Comment: well when i say java project, i mean a set of java files within a certain directory. i no i can compile them individually but the way i have it at the moment is all the files are in a JList and the user can choose the file they wish to compile, what I want to be able to do is add the project folders(all java files with the folder) to a JTree and then compile individual projects using the root node of the project, like you can compile a full project in eclipse by clicking on the project in the package screen and compiling then compiling all java files in the folder

Comment: the problems that i am experiencing is that i am getting an error that says 'cannot find symbol' and point to the class you are using a method from even do the files compiles find in eclipse and the import statement for the class you are using the method from is also there, it is saying i cannot find the class

Comment: You will need to make sure you have the corresponding .java file compiled beforehand and the resulting class.  Alternatively, collect all .java files in the list of compilation units you are passing to `compiler.getTask()`.  This latter approach should ensure that circular dependencies (if any) are resolved correctly

Answer (score 3):

- try using [shrinkwrap](http://www.jboss.org/shrinkwrap), it's very easy to use...

Comment: Just reading about shrinkwrap here, seems simple enough to use alright. Are you suggesting to move all the files for each project into a new 'ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class,"archive.jar")' and then compile the jar files then is it?

Answer (score 1):

You could enumerate the files (and directories recursively, if desired) under the specified project directory and compile them one-by-one the way you do now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the output directory in the compiler classpath. Notice how I include `targetDirectory` in the classpath below:

```
/**
 * Compiles Java source-code.
 * <p/>
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
public final class JavaCompiler
{
    private List<Path> sourcePath = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Path> classPath = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Set<DebugType> debugOptions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(DebugType.LINES,
        DebugType.SOURCE, DebugType.VARIABLES));

    /**
     * Sets the compiler classpath.
     * <p/>
     * @param sourcePath the paths to search for the source format of dependent classes
     * @throws NullPointerException if sourcePath is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if sourcePath refers to a non-existent path or a non-directory
     * @return the JavaCompiler
     */
    public JavaCompiler sourcePath(List<Path> sourcePath)
    {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(sourcePath, "sourcePath may not be null");
        for (Path path: sourcePath)
        {
            if (!Files.exists(path))
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("sourcePath refers to non-existant path: " + path.
                    toAbsolutePath());
            }
            if (!Files.isDirectory(path))
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("sourcePath refers to a non-directory: " + path.
                    toAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

        this.sourcePath = ImmutableList.copyOf(sourcePath);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the compiler classpath.
     * <p/>
     * @param classPath the paths to search for the compiled format of dependent classes
     * @throws NullPointerException if classPath is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if classPath refers to a non-existent path
     * @return the JavaCompiler
     */
    public JavaCompiler classPath(List<Path> classPath)
    {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(classPath, "classPath may not be null");
        for (Path path: classPath)
        {
            if (!Files.exists(path))
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("classPath refers to non-existant path: " + path.
                    toAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

        this.classPath = ImmutableList.copyOf(classPath);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Indicates the kind of debugging information the generated files should contain.
     * <p/>
     * @param debugOptions the kind of debugging information the generated files should contain. By
     * default all debugging information is generated.
     * @return the JavaCompiler object
     */
    public JavaCompiler debug(DebugType... debugOptions)
    {
        this.debugOptions.clear();
        this.debugOptions.addAll(Arrays.asList(debugOptions));
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Compiles the source code.
     * <p/>
     * @param sourceFiles the source files to compile
     * @param targetDirectory the directory to compile into. This path included in the compiler
     * classpath.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if sourceFiles, targetDirectory are null; or if sourceFiles
     * refers to a non-existent file or a non-file; or if targetDirectory is not a directory
     * @throws CompilationException if the operation fails
     */
    public void run(final Collection<Path> sourceFiles, final Path targetDirectory)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, CompilationException
    {
        if (sourceFiles == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("sourceFiles may not be null");
        if (sourceFiles.isEmpty())
            return;
        for (Path file: sourceFiles)
        {
            if (!Files.exists(file))
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("sourceFiles refers to a non-existant file: "
                    + file.toAbsolutePath());
            }
            if (!Files.isRegularFile(file))
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("sourceFiles refers to a non-file: "
                    + file.toAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        if (targetDirectory == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("targetDirectory may not be null");
        if (!Files.exists(targetDirectory))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("targetDirectory must exist: " + targetDirectory.
                toAbsolutePath());
        }
        if (!Files.isDirectory(targetDirectory))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("targetDirectory must be a directory: " + targetDirectory.
                toAbsolutePath());
        }
        Set<Path> uniqueSourceFiles = ImmutableSet.copyOf(sourceFiles);
        Set<Path> uniqueSourcePath = ImmutableSet.copyOf(sourcePath);
        final javax.tools.JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        if (compiler == null)
        {
            throw new AssertionError("javax.tools.JavaCompiler is not available. Is tools.jar missing "
                + "from the classpath?");
        }
        final DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
        final StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null,
            null);

        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits;
        try
        {
            Set<File> modifiedFiles = getModifiedFiles(uniqueSourceFiles, uniqueSourcePath,
                targetDirectory, new HashSet<Path>());
            if (modifiedFiles.isEmpty())
                return;
            compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(modifiedFiles);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new CompilationException(e);
        }
        final List<Path> effectiveClasspath = new ArrayList<>();
        effectiveClasspath.add(targetDirectory);
        effectiveClasspath.addAll(classPath);
        final List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add("-cp");
        options.add(Joiner.on(File.pathSeparatorChar).join(effectiveClasspath));

        final StringBuilder debugLine = new StringBuilder("-g:");
        for (DebugType type: debugOptions)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case LINES:
                {
                    debugLine.append("lines,");
                    break;
                }
                case SOURCE:
                {
                    debugLine.append("source,");
                    break;
                }
                case VARIABLES:
                {
                    debugLine.append("vars,");
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError(type);
            }
        }
        if (!debugOptions.isEmpty())
        {
            debugLine.deleteCharAt(debugLine.length() - ",".length());
            options.add(debugLine.toString());
        }

        if (!uniqueSourcePath.isEmpty())
        {
            options.add("-sourcepath");
            options.add(Joiner.on(File.pathSeparatorChar).join(uniqueSourcePath));
        }
        options.add("-s");
        options.add(targetDirectory.toString());
        options.add("-d");
        options.add(targetDirectory.toString());
        final Writer output = null;
        final CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(output, fileManager, diagnostics, options, null,
            compilationUnits);
        final boolean result = task.call();
        try
        {
            printDiagnostics(diagnostics, options, sourceFiles);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new BuildException(e);
        }
        if (!result)
            throw new CompilationException();
        try
        {
            fileManager.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new BuildException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the java source-code file corresponding to a class name.
     * <p/>
     * @param className the fully-qualified class name to look up
     * @param sourcePath the source-code search path
     * @return null if no match was found
     */
    private static File getJavaSource(String className, Set<File> sourcePath)
    {
        // TODO: check for class files instead of source
        for (File path: sourcePath)
        {
            File result = classNameToFile(path, className);
            if (!result.exists())
                continue;
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a class name to its source-code file.
     * <p/>
     * @param sourcePath the source-code search path
     * @param className the fully-qualified class name
     * @return the source-code file
     */
    private static File classNameToFile(File sourcePath, String className)
    {
        return new File(sourcePath, className.replace(".", "/") + ".java");
    }

    /**
     * Displays any compilation errors.
     * <p/>
     * @param diagnostics the compiler diagnostics
     * @param options the command-line options passed to the compiler
     * @param sourceFiles the source files to compile
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    private void printDiagnostics(final DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics,
        final List<String> options, final Collection<Path> sourceFiles) throws IOException
    {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JavaCompiler.class.getName() + ".stderr");
        int errors = 0;
        int warnings = 0;
        boolean firstTime = true;
        for (Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic: diagnostics.getDiagnostics())
        {
            if (firstTime)
            {
                firstTime = false;
                StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
                message.append("Invoking: javac ");
                for (String token: options)
                    message.append(token).append(" ");
                message.append(Joiner.on(" ").join(sourceFiles));
                log.debug(message.toString());
            }
            JavaFileObject source = diagnostic.getSource();
            if (source == null)
                log.error(diagnostic.getMessage(null));
            else
            {
                StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
                message.append(source.getName());
                if (diagnostic.getLineNumber() != Diagnostic.NOPOS)
                    message.append(":").append(diagnostic.getLineNumber());
                message.append(": ").append(diagnostic.getMessage(null));
                log.error(message.toString());
                try (BufferedReader reader =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(source.openInputStream())))
                {
                    String line = null;
                    for (long lineNumber = 0, size = diagnostic.getLineNumber(); lineNumber < size;
                        ++lineNumber)
                    {
                        line = reader.readLine();
                        if (line == null)
                            break;
                    }
                    if (line != null)
                    {
                        log.error(line);
                        message = new StringBuilder();
                        for (long i = 1, size = diagnostic.getColumnNumber(); i < size; ++i)
                            message.append(" ");
                        message.append("^");
                        log.error(message.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            switch (diagnostic.getKind())
            {
                case ERROR:
                {
                    ++errors;
                    break;
                }
                case NOTE:
                case OTHER:
                case WARNING:
                case MANDATORY_WARNING:
                {
                    ++warnings;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError(diagnostic.getKind());
            }
        }
        if (errors > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            message.append(errors).append(" error");
            if (errors > 1)
                message.append("s");
            log.error(message.toString());
        }
        if (warnings > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            message.append(warnings).append(" warning");
            if (warnings > 1)
                message.append("s");
            log.warn(message.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the source-code files that have been modified.
     * <p/>
     * @param sourceFiles the source files to process
     * @param sourcePath the source file search path
     * @param targetDirectory the directory to compile into
     * @param unmodifiedFiles files that are known not to have been modified
     * @return all changed source-code files that are accepted by the filter
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    private Set<File> getModifiedFiles(final Set<Path> sourceFiles,
        final Set<Path> sourcePath, final Path targetDirectory, final Set<Path> unmodifiedFiles)
        throws IOException
    {
        // TODO: Right now all files are assumed to have been modified
        Set<File> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (Path path: sourceFiles)
            result.add(path.toFile());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the command-line representation of the object.
     * <p/>
     * @param sourceFiles the source files to compile
     * @param targetDirectory the directory to compile into
     * @param sourcePath the source file search path
     * @return the command-line representation of the object
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the classpath contains non-file components
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    private List<String> toCommandLine(final Collection<Path> sourceFiles, final Path targetDirectory,
        final Collection<Path> sourcePath)
        throws IOException
    {
        final List<String> result = Lists.newArrayList("javac");
        if (!classPath.isEmpty())
        {
            result.add("-cp");
            try
            {
                final StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
                for (final Iterator<Path> i = classPath.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
                {
                    line.append(i.next().getParent().toString());
                    if (i.hasNext())
                        line.append(File.pathSeparatorChar);
                }
                result.add(line.toString());
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                // Occurs if URL does not refer to a file
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }
        for (File javaFile: getModifiedFiles(ImmutableSet.copyOf(sourceFiles),
            ImmutableSet.copyOf(sourcePath), targetDirectory, new HashSet<Path>()))
        {
            result.add(javaFile.getPath());
        }
        result.add("-d");
        result.add(targetDirectory.getParent().toString());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getClass().getName() + "[classPath=" + classPath + "]";
    }

    /**
     * The type of debugging information that generated files may contain.
     * <p/>
     * @author Gili Tzabari
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("PublicInnerClass")
    public enum DebugType
    {
        /**
         * No debugging information.
         */
        NONE,
        /**
         * Line number information.
         */
        LINES,
        /**
         * Local variable information.
         */
        VARIABLES,
        /**
         * Source file information.
         */
        SOURCE
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the classpath here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945379/programmatically-compile-java-files-and-include-other-jars-to-classpath